# How to prevent folder to deploy on Azure app serive

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I build a node js project for learning purpose and i deploy it on azure app serivce. It works fine, I don't face any kind of issue during deployment or after deployment. But i want to prevent or restrict a folder to not to deploy on azure app service during deployment. Suppose my folder name is logs. So how i prevent logs folder to not to deploy.
Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked some blogs and information, and some said that I would ignore it by adding files such as .npmignore. I didn't try these. When I saw the use of `rm -f folder_name`, I thought it was feasible.

So I tried the following, it works for me.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "rm -r /home/site/wwwroot/logs && node ./bin/www"
},
```

## **Principle:**

*Logs folder under wwwroot.*

When the deployment completed, delete the corresponding folder in the container.

**1. Linux.**

```
rm -r /home/site/wwwroot/logs
```

**2. Windows.**

```
rd/s/q D:\home\site\wwwroot\logs
```

[image]

*No logs folders under wwwroot.*

[image]